# SSO not working after .NET 4.5.1 update?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on

We have two server running .NET 4.5.1 and one running .NET 4.0. Before updating the first two, our SSO for forms authentication worked fine. Now, a user will appear authenticated on those first two servers, but not authenticated on the .NET 4.0 box.

All machine keys, decryption keys, cookie domains, etc, are all the same. No code was modified. We simply applied the 4.5.1 update to those two servers.

I've noticed for the 4.0 server, while our authentication cookie IS being passed up, it's not being recognized by the code (I threw a test page on the site and outputted some variables).

Has machine key encryption changed between 4.0 and 4.5.1? Do I need to apply some patch? Thanks.

Comment: Are all machines fully patched with the latest required Windows Update patches?  We did change the forms auth ticket format a while back, but this change was pushed out to all .NET versions as long as WU is enabled on the server.

Answer (score 4):

The encryption APIs have changed in 4.5 see this blog post for more detail - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/23/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-2.aspx

According to MS simply upgrading to 4.5 wouldn't affect the apps unless the web.configs have changed to target 4.5 which seems odd in your case.  You can try adding this attribute to each web.config to force .NET 2.0 compatibility-

```
<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" />
```